# xCode, ios show split-Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm looking for a show to show the "split keyboard" instead of the regular one.
I know that the user can drag the regular and show the "split", but is it possible to show directly the split?

Thanks (and sorry if very easy!)

Comment: This might not be possible, it doesn't really fit the UI paradigm seeing as the state of the keyboard is supposed to be the users choice.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not pre-set the location of the keyboard. It starts off in the way it sees best, and the user can adjust it if needs be.

Comment: @Franck If my answer was suitable for your needs, can you please accept? Thank you